# SQL Server reporting 2008 : getting started

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have just been told to get looking into using SQL server reporting. Does anyone have any good links they would recommend? 
Also can this be used for reporting on ASP.NET sites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the tutorials on MSDN to be a pretty good start.  Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167593.aspx).  You'll need to scroll down the page a bit to get to the Reporting Services section.

Yes, you can use SQL Server reports on ASP.NET web sites.  You'll need to include the [report viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) control on your page.  You can load the report from a report server or include it as a standalone report on the page as a .rdlc file.  Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252123%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for a walkthrough on how to include a stand-alone report on a web page.